# I want to send notification to specific group of users in my flutter app. How can i achieve it?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-notifications, flutter-notification

In my Firestore I have a collection GROUPS in which their are multiple groups. Whenever a new message is added to group I want to send notification to members of that group only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to achieve this,

1. subscribe user to group as a topic
   here i'm assuming your structure is

   -groups

   ```
    -group1
       -member1
       -member2
   -group1
       -member1
   ```

`_firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("groups/group1");`

2. fetch each user token and send a notification .
   [read more here](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use FCM "firebse Cloud messaging" but from a server side i suggest using Node-js "easy to install and use"

You have 2 methods to achieve this
1 - using Firebase cloud functions :
it has a triggers that can be fired whenever data has been written , removed or updated so you will use create trigger to send the notifications but unfortunately cloud function is not free any more you should be on blaze "paid subscription"

any way you can follow the documentation from here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

2- using snapshot listener to listing on the added data on this collection and then send the notifications its free if you upload the app.js to a free host

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#node.js_1

Sending notifications logic :
You can iterate on the users you have to send the notifications to
Or just assign for each a Topic so that when they can subscribe to it
If still not clear i'll post codes